# angular http get returns empty json data from php file

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I'm tying to set up a page with angular (version 1.6.10) which displays data from a php file (example_file.php) which creates a json page from a mysql database table using json_encode. Accessing the php file directly in a browser displays the json data correctly but when I use $http in angular to access it it returns nothing. If I save the generated json file as a json  file (example_file.json) and use that instead it works?

**example_file.php**

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 header("Content-Type: application/json");

 include('../../includes/Db.php');
 include('../../includes/item.php');
 $someItems = new Item();
 $items = $someItems->getItems();
 $data = array();
 foreach($items as $item){
   $data[] = array("id" => htmlspecialchars($item->id),
                  "image"  => htmlspecialchars($item->name),
                  "url"    => htmlspecialchars($item->url),
                  "alt"    => htmlspecialchars($item->alt_desc),
                  "title"  => htmlspecialchars($item->title),
                  "active" => htmlspecialchars($item->active),
                  "order"  => htmlspecialchars($item->order_by));
 }

 $json = json_encode($data);
 echo $json;
?>
```

this returns

```
[{"id":"18","image":"catalogue.jpg","url":"/catalogue","alt":"New catalogue out now!","title":"New catalogue","active":"1","order":"1"},{"id":"4","image":"item1.jpg","url":"\/item1\/","alt":"item1 alt description","title":"item1 description","active":"1","order":"2"},{"id":"7","image":"item2.jpg","url":"\/item2\/","alt":"","title":"item2 title","active":"1","order":"3"},{"id":"5","image":"item3","url":"\/item3\/","alt":"","title":"Item3 description","active":"1","order":"4"},{"id":"1","image":"item4.jpg","url":"","alt":"Item4 alt description","title":"item4 title","active":"1","order":"6"}]
```

**angular module moc.js**

```
(function () {

var moc = function($http) {
    var getItems = function () {
        return $http.get("data/example_file.php")
        .then(function(response) {
           return response.data;
        })
    };
    return {
       getItems: getItems,
    };
};
var module = angular.module("mocApp");
module.factory("moc", moc);
```

}());

**angular controller myCtrl.js**

```
(function () {
 var app = angular.module("mocApp");
 var homeCtrl = function($scope, moc) {
    var onComplete = function(data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    };
    var onError = function (reason) {
        $scope.error = "Could not fetch data";
    };
    moc.getItems().then(onComplete, onError);
 };
 app.controller("myCtrl", myCtrl);
}());
```

**html file item.html**

```
<div>
{{error}}
</div>

<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>url</th>
    <th>Order</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
    <td>
        {{item.name}}
    </td>
    <td>{{item.url}}</td>
    <td>{{item.order_by}}</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't think http.get can execute a php file. Why don't you export the return of the php to an actual .json file and access that?

Comment: w3s schools have an example using a php file https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_sql.asp. the php file generates the json data, angular then processes the json data

Comment: @FernandoAnia — It's just a URL. The client doesn't (and can't) care how the server determines what the response should be.

Comment: Can you confirm that there are no errors with the request in the browsers console?

Comment: @Clint - wasn't showing any errors except data null in firefox switched to chrome and shows Error Blocked by Client which wasn't displayed previously. Disabled add block plus and its good to go, so thanks for that Clint. Any thoughts on why adblock plus would be blocking it? Building the app then finding it breaks with adblock enabled after swithching to the live server would be a real pain!

Comment: @S.A I found this that may help: https://help.getadblock.com/support/solutions/articles/6000111830-adblock-is-blocking-or-broke-my-site-for-site-owners- and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991860/php-code-being-blocked-by-adblocker  Seems likely that your php file is named something that makes adblock think it's an ad. I would start there and try renaming the php file to something else. Also, would you update the question with the new information, that adblock is preventing the page from loading?